# Why IE11 in WIN10 does not contain emulation to EDGE comparing with IE11 on WIN8Server?

Tags: internet-explorer-11

We have really old application which run with IE compatibility mode 7. But now, we are about to start using PaloAlto VPN software which supports only IE11. Thus our application does not work via the PA software. Our idea was to run our application with emulation to EDGE, where it works perfectly. But when application is run in IE11 on WIN10, emulation to EDGE does not work simply because there is no possibility to emulate to EDGE on IE11 and WIN10. It works on WIN8Server and older windows, where IE11 enables emulation to EDGE.

Is there any possiblity how to emulate EDGE in IE11 on WIN10?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the F12 dev tools **Emulation** tab to emulate Edge in IE 11? If yes, you can refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/dn255001(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#mode).

Actually, that's a naming issue. Prior to Windows 10 when the Edge browser started, the compatibility modes listed the latest version (version of that browser) as "Edge" in IE. They renamed that setting when Win10 came out. In the article you can also find:

> **Edge (Default)** represents all the latest standards and features IE11
> supports.

In your case, you're emulating Edge in IE 11, so the "Edge" option is IE 11 actually. So you don't need to emulate Edge in IE 11 on Win10, just use IE 11 document mode which is the same thing.

Comment: Dear @YuZhou thanks for your reply, but I cannot agree with that because our application does not work in IE11 on WIN10 while the same application works fine in the EDGE or Chrome on the WIN10 (same machine). So there must be some differences causing that it not works in IE11.

Comment: You say "emulate to EDGE" in your question what I understand is set the [emulation mode to Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2v5MS.jpg) in IE11 F12 dev tools. It is the same as set the [emulation mode to 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNknG.png) in IE11 F12 dev tools. And the emulation mode to Edge in F12 **doesn't means Edge browser**. It just means the latest IE 11. This is what I explained in my answer.

Comment: You say "works fine in the EDGE or Chrome on the WIN10 (same machine)", I think it means **Edge browser**. Of course, the results that app running in Edge browser and IE browser are not the same. You need to change your code to make it supported in IE not only change the emulation mode in IE.

Comment: Dear Yu Zhou, thanks, but this is not possible. We are using old technologies like JBoss Seam, Richfaces and other and we were never be able to manage to behave correctly in IE without emulation. If emulation in IE on WIN10 to  IE11 means the same as to emulate to EDGE, why application worsk fine on WIN8 where we emulate in IE11 to EDGE and on WIN10 not? On WIN10 in IE11 no emulation to EDGE and application does not work.

Comment: Dear Vlastimil Unucka, I can fully understand your situation now. The different results may due to different IE 11 versions in win8 and win10. You can compare the versions in IE 11 using **Tools-> About Internet Explorer**. Unfortunately, it's impossible to emulate to Edge if IE 11 doesn't has this option in F12 emulation tab.

Comment: Dear Yu Zhou, please check my videos to understand our situation correctly: 1 - WIN10 / EDGE - no emulation needed, dialog works fine as in chrome screencast.com/t/AbZIewwpZ 2 - WIN10 / IE11 - emulation to EDGE, dialog does not work screencast.com/t/F0GvajpFhG 3 - WIN8 / IE11 - emulation to EDGE, dialog works fine https://www.screencast.com/t/zC7V96y0ui1

Comment: Is there any possibility how to allow emulation to EDGE in IE11 on WIN10? Some change in Windows registers or another hack? I suppose not - thus it is very sad situation for us.

Comment: No, I think it's impossible. There's no such registry to change this. As the IE version is determined by the OS version. And that version of IE in win10 determins that it won't have the Edge emulation option.

Comment: Yu Zhou, thank you very much for your help. We thought that the result will be like this. We will rewrite our code and we will not use dialogs which do not work.